# HTML to send a pre-written email

Tags: php, html, email

I have put a website up on the internet, and I want to have a function where a user can enter their email address into a form and when submitted, they will receive a pre-set email.

There are other questions, but none of them seemed to help me.

I have basic code here:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mail">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Here is the send.php

```
<?php
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
?>
<html>
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $mail ?>"><button>SEND</button></a>
</html>
```

Please excuse the fact that you have to press send twice, I will change that.
What I want to do, is send the user (email is represented by `$mail`) a pre written document via email, not as an attachment, but a the composition of the email.

I am unsure as to weather i can just use a word document, or there is complex code behind it.

Since i am only familiar with basic visual elements, please could you explain what parts of the code do what, as i may want to tweak it.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You're not putting anything into the body of the mail. Set up a string with your template and make that the body of your email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Fred said, the best way to approach this is via [PHP's mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). When send.php runs, you can include PHP code like

```
mail($mail, "My Email Subject", "<html><b>Email Message</b></html>", $headers);
```

Where your header variable will have to contain all the necessary information to tell your client's mail software that the string message contains HTML that should be parsed. An example header setup is as follows, from [CSS Trick's lovely example](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) for this problem:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Noting that you can replace the `strip_tags` call with whatever set emails you want. Then, you can replace my `<html><b>Email Message</b></html>` with whatever code you want to make a nicely formatted email.

Using PHP's `mail()` function also makes it so you do not need to click submit twice.